# Hide ajax Path in JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, relative-path

Lets say I am using `$.post` in jQuery. The correct syntax for that is `$.post("xxx.php",{/*options*/},function(data))` How can I make it so that, in this case, `xxx.php` doesn't actually show up in the JavaScript. Can I put a relative path like `/login` or something. And if that were to work, would it be referenced to the `index.php` file in there. Or, can I use an encoded version, which seems pointless because you can easily decode it. I just don't want people seeing directly into my paths, and than making extra scripts to make sure the files were visited by a `XHTTP request`.

Any answers, links, or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not an adequate model. If you want a browser to be able to send data somewhere, you have to accept that a human being will be able to as well, and you can't control the data they send. All you can do is sanitise it.

Comment: @lonesomeday It's not obvious that the question is about obscuring the data. It's about obscuring the *paths*. That's a reasonable ask.

Comment: Why do you want to obscure part or all of the request URL?

Comment: Because say I have the PHP document login.php. I don't want people to be able to go to that page, and have any sort of change at getting a view directory hack to work. I really just don't want them to able to see any paths at all for anything other than pictures that deviate from the home folder

Comment: @JonahAllibone have you considered using a framework that doesn't reveal file-based paths at all? Django is an example of such a framework. There must be a PHP-based solution that does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the age-old method of having the application server find all the pages from arguments in the query string. Then all your ajax requests can go to the same "file", but that file would return a different php include based on the parameters.

The mapping itself may be a challenge to manage, but that's a different SO question.

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Apache was not in his tags or his question.

Comment: @kojiro probably because he thinks this is a client side issue.

Comment: `How can I make it so that, in this case, xxx.php doesn't actually show up in the JavaScript. Can I put a relative path like /login or something` is exactly what mod_rewrite does.

Comment: I don't know Apache. Is there anyway to do a similar thing in PHP?

Comment: no. PHP is run /after/ the web server figures out what is being requested. so you need to do your configuring at the web server level.

Comment: @Esailija maybe, but it's still an unqualified assumption that Apache is even in play here. It's possible to use PHP with nginx, cherokee, lighttpd, IIS, and other web servers.

Comment: @kojiro, for IIS there are multiple url rewriters, nginx has rewrite, cherokee has [Redirection](http://serverfault.com/questions/118208/how-to-port-apache-rewrite-rules-to-cherokee), lighttpd has url.rewrite and so on. It took me a few of mins googling with "x mod_rewrite equivalent" where x is any web server you mentioned. Perhaps a better answer would just say and explain URL rewriting in general instead of just saying mod_rewrite and assume the OP knows what it implies but it still drives the point home.

Comment: the reason i gave a URL /as well/ as just saying "mod_rewrite" was that if the OP didn't know what mod_rewrite was, he/she could just click the link and find out. that at least would give an idea of what to look out for on whatever platform.